# Customizing less colors

Tags: emacs, colors, less, color-management

When using less in OS X, how can I customize the colors with with things are displayed? When I run less within an ansi-term in Emacs the colors don't come out nicely.

```
$ less --version
less 418
Copyright (C) 1984-2007 Mark Nudelman
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For OSX, this refers to Emacs 22.1.1; Fedora with Emacs 24 has the same behavior.

Emac's ansi-term supports ***8 colors***.  That is all that ANSI specified, and "ansi-term" is named appropriately.  The [`eterm-color`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_Emacs) terminal description in ncurses is used for this terminal type.  Emacs sets `TERM` to this value ([see source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/term.el#n1416)):

```
(defvar term-term-name "eterm-color"
  "Name to use for TERM.
Using \"emacs\" loses, because bash disables editing if $TERM == emacs.")
```

If you override `TERM`, e.g., to tell applications that it has more colors, then the extra colors will not be used.  Likewise, hard-coded applications which ignore the terminal database cannot use extra colors either.

While Emacs can use more than 8 colors in a terminal, *ansi-term* does not.  Reading the [source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/term.el#n2690), look for `term-ansi-current-color`, and see that there is only [logic for 30-37, 39, 40-47 and 49](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/term.el#n3133):

```
   ;; Foreground
   ((and (>= parameter 30) (<= parameter 37))
    (setq term-ansi-current-color (- parameter 29)))

   ;; Reset foreground
   ((eq parameter 39)
    (setq term-ansi-current-color 0))

   ;; Background
   ((and (>= parameter 40) (<= parameter 47))
    (setq term-ansi-current-bg-color (- parameter 39)))

   ;; Reset background
   ((eq parameter 49)
    (setq term-ansi-current-bg-color 0))
```

You may be able to change the palette of colors used by your *terminal*, but there is no way to make *ansi-term* differ from that (it will use the first 8 colors even if Emacs can use 256).

Further reading:

- [AnsiTerm](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnsiTerm) (Emacs wiki)
- [AnsiTermHints](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnsiTermHints) (Emacs wiki)

For Emacs other than *ansi-term*:

- [How to make Emacs terminal colors the same as Emacs GUI colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63950/how-to-make-emacs-terminal-colors-the-same-as-emacs-gui-colors)
- [How do you apply a Emacs custom color theme in console mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374802/how-do-you-apply-a-emacs-custom-color-theme-in-console-mode)

Also:

- [term.el](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/term.el) (Emacs source code for *ansi-term*)
- [ansi-color.el](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/ansi-color.el) (Emacs source code)
- [term/tty-colors.el](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/term/tty-colors.el) (Emacs source code)
- [term/xterm.el](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/term/xterm.el) (Emacs source code)

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thanks! Coincidentally I asked [this other question](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/posts/24784/) today in Emacs.SE before reading this answer you wrote. What you have here seems appropriate for that other Q as well!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's partially a function of your terminal type, for one.

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

This post might also be worth a look, titled: [Piping Ls Through Less With Colors on Mac OS X](http://mockingeye.com/piping-ls-through-less-with-colors-on-mac-os/index.html/). Also this setting might prove helpful.

```
  $ export LESS="-erX" 

  -or-

  $ export LESS="-eRX"
```

You can consult the man page for `less` to find out more about the various switches above.

Comment: `-R` may be preferable over `-r` in this case.

Comment: Thanks slm and @StephaneChazelas - How can I change those colors then? Sometimes, I run less within a shell within Emacs (where `echo $TERM` returns `eterm-color`). Within a regular terminal, I get `xterm-256color`and within tmux I get `screen`.

Comment: @user815423426 - some of the coloring (ls output) is controlled through these files: `/etc/DIR_COLORS*`. I do not believe there is any central resource where you can control the colors, rather you have to control them per application such as emacs, vim, etc.